# al ejecutarlo dice que falta el parentesis derecho

Tags: oracle-10g

```
CREATE TABLE tbProveedor
(
  id numeric(10) not null,
  nombre varchar2(50) not null,
  correo varhar2(50),
  constraint PK_tbProveedor primary key(id, nombre)
```

Comment: Si observas, te falta cerrar el `CREATE  TABLE` con un paréntesis al final de todo, y poner punto y coma: **`CREATE TABLE tbProveedor
(
  id numeric(10) not null,
  nombre varchar2(50) not null,
  correo varhar2(50),
  constraint PK_tbProveedor primary key(id, nombre) );`**

Answer (score -1):

Solo agrega un paréntesis y un punto y coma al final

```
CREATE TABLE tbProveedor
(    
   id numeric(10) not null,
   nombre varchar2(50) not null,  
   correo varhar2(50),   
   constraint PK_tbProveedor primary key(id, nombre)
);
```